# Showing that a finite measure over S, the collection of cylinder, is $\sigma$ finite.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X = \{1,\dots,d \}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ the set of all bilateral sequences.

Define a elementary cylinder $C = \{x \in X: (x(p),\dots,x(q)) = (a_{p},\dots,a_{q}) \}$ where $(a_{p},\dots,a_{q}) \in \{ 1,\dots,d \}^{q-p+1}$, $q \geq p$ and $x = (x(i))_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

Define a cylinder of radius $q-p+1$, $\mathcal{C} = \{x \in X: (x(p),\dots,x(q)) \in U \}$ where $U \subset \{ 1,\dots,d \}^{q-p+1}$ and $q \geq p$, we can see that $\mathcal{C} $ is a finite disjoint union of elementary cylinders, and $C_{r}$ the collection of all cylinder of radius $r$.

Define $\mathcal{S} = \{\varnothing\} \cup C_{1} \cup C_{2} \cup \dots$, its easy to see that $\mathcal{S}$ ia a algebra

Define $P(\{x:(x(m),\dots,x(n))\in U\}):=\displaystyle\sum_{(u_{m},\dots,u_{n})\in U\subset \{1,\dots,d\}^{n-m+1}}d^{-(n-m+1)}$.

$P$ is well defined and is a finite measure.

I want to show that $P$ is $\sigma$-finite with the following theorem.

$\textbf{Theorem}$ Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a algebra and $\mu$ a finite measure over $\mathcal{A}$.

If for all sequences $\{A_{n}\} \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that $A_{n} \neq \varnothing $ for all $n$, $A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}$ and $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_{n} =\varnothing$ implies $\lim \mu(A_{n}) = 0$ so $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

What i want to show now is that if $\{ A_{n} \} \subset \mathcal{S}$ such that $A_{n+1} \subsetneq A_{n} $ and $A_{n} \neq \varnothing$ for all $n$ so $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_{n} \neq \varnothing$.

My attempet so far: assume the above conditions, let $A_{n} = \{ x \in X:(x(p_{n})\dots,x(q_{n})) \in U_{n} \}$, $U_{n} \subset \{1,\dots,d \}^{q_{n} - p_{n} +1}$ we can assume that $p_{n+1} \leq p_{n}$ and $q_{n} \leq q_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

One can show that $p_{n} \rightarrow -\infty$ or $q_{n} \rightarrow \infty$, lets assume that $q_{n} \rightarrow \infty$.

Any help will be appreciated.